# What is the hierarchy between :root * html and body and when use one or other?

Tags: html, css

I want to know two things:

1. The hierarchy between :root * html and body on css. I know when [css is used with html :root is the same that html, but this first have higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root). And between * and body? I confused because * is for all the style too.
2. When do you recommend use one or another.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: your question is not clear, you cannot compare `*` with `body` since they don't select the same elements

Comment: I see in some web page the selector * to apply some style. I think this elements was comparable, but now i know that they don't. So, how would the hierarchy look (:root -> html -> body)? And in what place and for what can be use the selector *

@TemaniAfif

Comment: :roor is the same as html then -> body.

Comment: Thanks! I understand @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0):

`*` refers to all elements

body refers to the body tag

HTML & :root refers to the whole document aka the HTML tag just ones higher in specificity than the other

Comment: Ey! Thanks @lambsbaaacode. But what i still don't know is the specificity from this four elements. I mean, i know the next:  :root is the very high, the body is the very low, but, what about * and html, both share the same level of specificity? Or the order is other?

Comment: @JuanMPCastillo I don't know, I mean honestly sometimes you have to use HTML and :root together for some browsers

Comment: i understand. Thanks for the comment, time and attention.